# erlang: how to protect database against SQL injection inside json field

Tags: postgresql, erlang

I am using epgsql(https://github.com/epgsql/epgsql) lib which allows writing queries like this:

```
  "INSERT INTO my_table"
  "(item_id, json_data) "
  "VALUES ($1, $2) "
  "ON CONFLICT "
  "DO NOTHING "
  "RETURNING *;",
```

And then call such queries with different parameters. In general, we expect a wide range of incoming data without any pre-defined format. The only thing we expect is that it's a JSON of the following format:
`{"field_name": "long value from the user with a potential injection of the SQL code I need to be protected from"}`

The question I am having is how do I protect the query from something bad. E.g. that someone enters something like `; DROP table ...  ---` or anything like that?

Comment: If that is a proper parameterised query then you don't need to do anything. That's why you should always use parameterised queries.

Comment: But is that guaranteed that it's not possible to add something like DROP table; into a query parameter?

Comment: If you are worried about incompetent or malicious code in the library then you are going to have to review the code. If not, a proper parameterised query is fine.

Comment: Of course they can put something like '; DROP table ...  ---' in there (provided it is properly encapsulated into JSON), but it will just be stored as data, not executed.  Unless there are bugs in epgsql

Answer (score 0):

In the situation when you provide a service for DB queries really very hard to do a call cleanup.

Only one option coming to my mind:

Normalise the incoming command with upper case, removing of double-spaces, split a command into ";"-lines etc. and then you can potentially do a dictionary search for text as "DROP TABLE…" or "DELETE FROM…" to mark command as a dangerous and prevent execution, other cases can be also provided, but this creates a knowledge base to be maintained.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to write it by yourself considering other language's implementation.